# Click a button on Chrome with Python, WITHOUT webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a button on a website on my over Windows+R opened Chrome tab (Vers. 3.X) with Python.
Normally you would easily open Chrome via webdriver like this:

```
ATH = "c:\program files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

but it always openes Chrome without addons, so I would have to click the "accept cookies" button automatically as well- which is very hard. To go around this, I open it via Windows+R like this.

```
pg.hotkey('winleft','r')
pg.typewrite('www.techwithtim.net')
pg.typewrite('\n')
```

-So far, so good, but now I want to click a button on the webside (I guess via webdriver is the only option for this?) on the currently opened tab:

```
#Press OK BUTTON 
ok = WebDriverWait(driver.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Start Programming!")
))
ok.click()
```

But it doesn't work when opening Chrome via Windows+R
Here is the whole code:

```
import os
import random
import string
import subprocess
import time
import tkinter
import pynput
import pyautogui as pg

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from turtle import goto
from tkinter import Tk
from urllib3.util import url

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

##############Use Windows + R to open sort##############

#Press Windows + R to open Chrome
pg.hotkey('winleft','r')
pg.typewrite('www.techwithtim.net')
pg.typewrite('\n')
time.sleep(6)

#Use webdriver to open Chrome - but no Addons, so = cookie-window :O
#PATH = "c:\program files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
#driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#Press OK BUTTON 
ok = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Start Programming!")
))
ok.click()
```

Comment: "but it always openes Chrome without addons, so I would have to click the "accept cookies" button automatically as well- which is very hard." What "addons" are you talking about? Also, if the "accept cookies" button is in the DOM, I can't imagine it is so difficult to click.

Comment: you probably want to open using an existing profile...  some addons/extensions may not be compatible with Selenium, but give it a try.  You can't control a browser via wire protocol if it wasn't launched in dev mode.  (and you receive the sessionID)  Your only other option would be a robot framework for the OS you're using.  (a bit of a pain really so try using existing profile first.)

Comment: but it always openes Chrome without addons, so I would have to click the "accept cookies" button automatically as well- which is very hard. -  I could not see any accept cookie bar or notification

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to activate addons when starting chrome so the cookie-windows doesnt pop up (See **"1.)"**). After this, I have used "pyautogui" to make my mouse click my button (See **"2.)"**).

**1.)**
For this, this video has helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fx1hbZMVS7k
(For key-points of the video, see below).

This is the code I've used to make chrome run without the cookie-windows popping up:

```
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('INSERT HERE THE NAME OF YOUR CHROME-EXTENSIONFILE.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Make sure to have the following files are in the same folder as your python code (in my case in the same folder as of the Visual-Studio file)
-chromedriver
-your python-file
-your chrome extension crx file (make sure it says "crx3" - the latest version - here: http://crx-checker.appspot.com/).
If it doesnt say "crx3", I guess you haven't downloaded it directly from chromestore, as it normally should download the latest crx-version (At this date its crx3).

**Where can I get the crx file of my chrome extension?**
Copy the link of your chrome-store-extension like this one:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/i-dont-care-about-cookies/fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja

copy it in here and download the latest crx version:
https://standaloneinstaller.com/online-tools/crx-downloader

I have used "I don't care about cookies" instead of "uBlock", which I've intended to use before but "uBlock" doesnt deactivate cookies from default. Sadly the extension always gets reseted after every program-start, so "I don't care about cookies" needed to do the job for me here.

**2.)**
*In case you are able to click the elements on your website already, you can skip reading this:*
How to make your mouse click buttons on a website:

-Open your website, or whatever you want to click on

1. Get the position of your mouse cursor:

This is the code I have used for that:

```
import pyautogui

#gives you 5 seconds to move your cursor to the right position
time.sleep(5)
#prints the positon of your mouse in the console
print(pyautogui.position())
```

2. Implementing the clicking the button-option via mouse:

Now you can copy this code to your program:

import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(YOUR X POSITION, YOUR Y POSITION)
#an example: pyautogui.click(11, 22)

Hope this helps anyone. Sorry for mistakes in any case, Im still a newbie to python.